# Jmeter can not get value with Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: jmeter

I am new with Jmeter. I want to get value from response and use it in another sampler. I did following step but it alway return default value. First I test my regEx with RegTester and I got the result
[image]

And below is my config in Regular Expression Extractor
[image]

And I try to check the result in another sampler but it return default value
[image]

[image]

Please help me on this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch "Response Field to Test" to **Text Response**

As per [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) documentation:

> **Text Response** - the response text from the server, i.e. the body, excluding any HTTP headers.
>
> **Document (text)** - the extract text from various type of documents via Apache Tika (see [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Document view section).

So "Document (text)" needs to be used when you're downloading i.e. auto-generated file and want to check that the file contains a certain phrase.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for comprehensive information on using Assertions in JMeter tests.

---

It might be more handy to use [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) which is available since JMeter 3.0. It simplifies working with JSON data as [JSONPath language](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) is much easier than Perl5-style regular expressions, especially when it comes to getting separate values from multiple lines or conditional selection (i.e. "get all SKU where virtual stocks > 10".

Comment: I change to use JSON Path and it works. Thank for helping me